# SmartOS: How to configure IPFilter (IPF) loopback firewall rule?

Tags: firewall, nat, solaris, smartos, ipfilter

I have a SmartOS machine with one external IP address. One of my websites needs loopback access. However, if I try to

```
curl https://www.example.com
```

it simply times out from within a zone. From within the global zone I receive the following error message:

```
connect to 1.2.3.4 port 443 failed: Connection refused
```

My firewall is setup like this (`/etc/ipf/ipf.conf`):

```
## Allow Inbound Ports
pass in quick on vioif0 proto tcp from any to any port = 22 keep state
pass in quick on vioif0 proto tcp from any to any port = 80 keep state
pass in quick on vioif0 proto tcp from any to any port = 443 keep state
pass in quick on vioif0 proto icmp from any to any icmp-type echo
## Allow Out Ports
pass out quick on vioif0 all keep state
## Block all else
block in quick log first on vioif0 all
block out quick log first on vioif0 all
```

Maybe it is also the NAT causing the problems (`/etc/ipf/ipnat.conf`):

```
rdr vioif0 from any to any port = 80 -> 10.0.0.2 port 80 tcp
rdr vioif0 from any to any port = 443 -> 10.0.0.2 port 443 tcp
map vioif0 from 10.0.0.0/24 to any -> 0/32 proxy port ftp ftp/tcp
map vioif0 from 10.0.0.0/24 to any -> 0/32 portmap tcp/udp auto
map vioif0 from 10.0.0.0/24 to any -> 0/32
```

Any pointers?